# regarding Regex operation in KNIME

Tags: regex, knime, alteryx

This below formula is in alteryx workflow.

if(REGEX_Match([*CurrentField*],'   (',0)) then 'string to display something'
elseif(REGEX_Match([*CurrentField*],'a',0)) then 'another string to display'

Can you explain me what above function is trying to perform and how to achieve this in KNIME.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this if/else syntax in KNIME you can use [Column Expressions](https://hub.knime.com/knime/nodes/Column_Expressions*2_0ji_xeG-SudFu-) node. In this node there is also *rexegMatcher* function that returns Boolean.

It can be something like this:

```
if (regexMatcher(column("column1"),"your_regex" )) {
    "string1"
} else if (regexMatcher(column("column1"),"your_regex2" )) {
    "string2"
} else {
    "string3"
}
```

Comment: Thanks :)But If I want to apply these operations on around 10 columns , do I need to copy paste the piece of code for all columns?

Comment: In that case you can use [Column List Loop Start](https://hub.knime.com/knime/nodes/Column_List_Loop_Start*NmCHLnBIGbvnDkb6) node that will in each iteration use one column from included columns (I suggest that in your data set you leave only columns you will loop over and others you just join later on, if any). In Column Expressions node you can access column by position instead of name. So you should use `column(0)` instead `column("column_name")` function in your code. Finish it with [Loop End (Column Append)](https://hub.knime.com/knime/nodes/Loop_End_Column_Append*CCMhDNWHYFXV506q) node.